# indexOf with Nothing Before String

Tags: javascript

I have a string which contains the following:

```
string = "GOAT,Speed,OCG GOAT";
```

I then have the following:

```
if(data.format.indexOf("GOAT") >= 0){

}
if(data.format.indexOf("OCG GOAT") >= 0){

}
```

Both of them naturally return as TRUE because "GOAT" is contained in both of them.
Is it possible to do an indexOf where nothing comes before the string so I can do only a check on "GOAT" and not have "OCG GOAT" return true? Because "GOAT" will always come first in the string.

Comment: What have you tried so far? I don't think that `indexOf` returns `true` in any case

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either check that the `indexOf` is equal to 0 (indicating that the substring you're searching for occurs at the very beginning of the haystack):

```
data.format.indexOf('GOAT') === 0
```

Or use `startsWith` instead:

```
data.format.startsWith('Goat')
```

Comment: Excellent. First solution worked perfectly for me. Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Using regular expressions could be a solution, too:

```js
const GOAT_REGEX = /^GOAT.*/g;

const SUCCESS = "GOAT,Speed,OCG GOAT";
const FAILURE = "Speed,OCG GOAT";

console.log('Should work (true is correct)', GOAT_REGEX.test(SUCCESS));
console.log('Should fail (false is correct)', GOAT_REGEX.test(FAILURE));
```